# Como puedo hacer que los datos introducidos en EditText de una actividad se guarden al salir y volver entrar a esta?

Tags: android

Somos un par de alumnos de secundaria que intentamos crear una pequeña  app para un trabajo. Nuestro problema es el siguiente: tras crear una actividad que pretendemos que sea un horario escolar en el que puedas apuntar las materias que tienes, hemos tenido el problema de que al escribir las materias  en el dicho horario, al salir de la app estas no se han guardado y volvemos a tener los espacios del horario en blanco. como podemos hacer para que estos datos introducidos se guarden. Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad, te invito a compartir tu código o lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento, ya que no es muy clara tu pregunta y no demuestra algún signo de esfuerzo. Saludos.

Comment: He reescrito la pregunta para que se entienda mejor, disculpa las molestias y haznos saber si puedes resolver nuestra duda. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Pueden usar varios métodos, desde un archivo de texto, base de datos o SharedPreferences, considero que lo más sencillo sería usar esto último.

Defines un método para guardar el valor deseado:

```
public void saveValuePreference(Context context, String identificador, String text) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences("mispreferencias", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(identificador, text);
    editor.commit();
}
```

y un método para obtener los valores cuando vuelvas a entrar a tu aplicación:

```
public String getValuePreference(Context context, String identificador) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("mispreferencias", MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getString(identificador, "");
}
```

Suponiendo que deseas guardar el valor de tu EditText , definimos un identificador llamado "miprimerdato", y como último parametro defines el valor del EditText:

```
saveValuePreference(getApplicationContext, "miprimerdato", EditText .getText().toString());
```

para obtener nuevamente el valor defines el identificador para obtener el dato de la preferencia:

```
String valorEditText = getValuePreference(getApplicationContext(), "miprimerdato");
```